# Dense board with sparse rook attacking

Tags: combinatorics

Given an $n\times n$ board. What is the smallest $k$ such that it is possible to set up the board so that every $k\times k$ square contains at least one rook, each rook is attacked by at most one other rook, and every unoccupied cell is attacked by some rook?

A similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896462/rooks-attacked-by-at-most-one-other-rook) was posted and solved. The difference between that question and this one is that in this question, we are only looking for one arrangement of the rooks so that every $k\times k$ square contains at least one rook, while in the other question, every $k\times k$ square should contain at least one rook for **any** arrangement satisfying the properties.

Comment: This problem is really similar to problem 2 of the 2014 IMO

Comment: If you put rooks on both diagonals, wouldn't each rook be attacked by two other rooks - those in the same row/column on the other diagonal?

Comment: @Shagnik Good point, I was wrong